Why am i getting node:internal/errors:490 ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err); Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]:
getRandomFood : async (req,res) =>{
    try {
        let randomFoodList=[];
        console.log(req.params.code);
        if(req.params.code){
            randomFoodList = await Food.aggregate([
                {$match : {code : req.params.code}},
                {$sample : {size : 3}},
                {$project : {__v:0}}
            ])
        }
        console.log(randomFoodList+"Pankaj");
        if(!randomFoodList.length){
            randomFoodList = await Food.aggregate([
                {$sample : {size : 3}},
                {$project : {__v:0}}
            ])
        }
        if(randomFoodList.length){
        res.status(200).json(randomFoodList);
        return;
        }else{
        res.status(404).json({status:false,message: 'No Food Found  '});return;}
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json(error);        }
    },

This is the code what i suppose to change in my code to run properly and get the data.
i tried to make changes with every res return from the code but still it is not returning and crashing. I have same error with one more function and other functions are running and getting the data.

Return your function response like below
return res.status... 
You are getting error becuase you are not returning response.
